# Why won't Visual Studio 2017 run Android emulator? (Gives error ANDROID_SDK_ROOT missing)

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-studio-2.3

- I just installed Visual Studio 2017.
- I started a Android Xamarin project from the template.
- Project built successfully.
- Then I attempted to run the app but the emulator failed.

I saw the following error:

> 1>Starting deploy Nexus_5X_API_22_Lollipop ... 
>   1>Starting emulator
>   Nexus_5X_API_22_Lollipop ...
>   1>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512
>   -no-boot-anim -avd Nexus_5X_API_22_Lollipop -prop monodroid.avdname=Nexus_5X_API_22_Lollipop 
>   1>PANIC: **Cannot find AVD**
>   system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT 1>Emulator
>   Nexus_5X_API_22_Lollipop cannot be started.
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>   [image]

I already have Android Studio 2.3 installed on this same machine.

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I have Android Studio 2.3 and a valid Environment variable named: 
ANDROID_SDK_HOME, which Android Studio uses, it seems that I needed to add a new environment variable that points to the same location as ANDROID_SDK_HOME but is named ANDROID_SDK_ROOT (for use in Visual Studio 2017).

First go to File Explorer and right-click This PC:

[image: this PC properties]

Choose Properties menu item and computer settings swill appear.
[image: windows properties]

Choose the Advanced System Settings link, on the left.

An new dialog box will appear -- System Properies with the advanced tab chosen for you.
[image: system properties dialog]

Click the Environment Variables... button and another dialog box will appear.

At the bottom under system variables, add your new variable named :
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT with the path that points to your ANDROID SDK on your machine.
[image: system environment variables.]

Once you save and close all the dialogs the Systen Environment Variable will be available.  I believe I had to restart Visual Studio and then after that it found ANDROID_SDK_HOME and started my emulator with no problem.

Comment: Hi, this answer you should include the location of the SDK which is C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk